# Using Next.js in Electron project, can't find right files after build

Tags: javascript, next.js, electron, electron-forge

I am using Electron with Nextjs to make an app. Everything is fine in dev environment. But error occur when I use electron-forge to build product.

ERROR:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLHBS.png)

I can't access the pages which are used getStaticProps from fetch data. Static pages (no fetching) is fine. Click the link will return a blank page with a suspicious URL.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDqxB.png)

Although the URL looks wrong, it runs well on other request like fetch '_next/static/chunks'

I paste contents of package.json here.

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist renderer/.next renderer/out",
    "dev": "electron .",
    "build": "next build renderer && next export renderer",
    "pack-app": "npm run build && electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "npm run build && electron-builder",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "startweb": "npm start renderer",
    "package": "electron-forge package",
    "make": "electron-forge make",
    "build-static": "next build renderer && next export renderer && npm run repair-path",
    "repair-path": "replace-in-files --string \"/_next/static\" --replacement \"./_next/static\" renderer/out/index.html"
  },
  "build": {
    "asar": true,
    "files": [
      "main",
      "renderer/out"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.1.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.1.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.1.0",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.7",
    "electron": "^12.0.2",
    "next": "^13.2.4",
    "prisma": "^4.11.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.11.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.1.0",
    "electron-next": "^3.1.5",
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-webcam": "^7.0.1",
    "replace-in-files-cli": "^2.2.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  }
}
```

I use 'npm run build' and 'npm run make' to build app.

The file structure looks like this:
app
├ main
├   ├ index.js (electron entrance file)
├   └ preload.js
├ out
├   └ APP output(also has all next data resource inside)
└ renderer
├ .next
├ components
├ out
├ pages
└ next.config.js

And here is the main.js:

```
  await prepareNext('./renderer')

  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      preload: join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
    },
  })

  const url = isDev
    ? 'http://localhost:8000'
    : format({
        pathname: join(app.getAppPath(), 'renderer/out/index.html'),
        // pathname: join(__dirname, '../renderer/out/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true,
      });
  mainWindow.loadURL(url)
})
```